# Can I award a bounty before 7 days has elapsed?

Tags: support, bounty

The [help page for bounties](https://superuser.com/help/bounty) says:

> The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day.

Does this mean I can manually award a bounty after 24 hours have elapsed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. One day after the bounty is started, you may award it to any answer you choose by clicking the blue bounty number (e.g. "+100") next to it. You may not award the bounty until that full day has elapsed. The age of the answer receiving the bounty does not matter.

Further reading: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/295684)

Comment: Thanks. I was worried I missed a deadline to start a bounty for the "Philantropist" hat. As an aside this question should get "The Hatter" but I don't have it yet ... I suppose I need an upvote ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There's a short, one day wait, then anytime within 7 days *and* a 24 hour grace period.